# Errors just switching between dev and prod mode

Tags: magento2.2, developer-mode, production-mode

Magento CE 2.2.6 PHP 7.1.24 in production mode, frontend was working with just few bugs but i have a spam of

```
[2018-11-27 10:02:57] main.CRITICAL: The element 'header-wrapper' already has a child with alias 'topSearch' {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The element 'header-wrapper' already has a child with alias 'topSearch' at /home/mipxidih/paganostore.com/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:611)"} []
```

each minute in exception.log

than i've just switched from production to dev mode with

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/*
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

and navigating to frontend start giving

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'ifConfig': The attribute 'ifConfig' is not allowed.
Line: 243


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'ifConfig': The attribute 'ifConfig' is not allowed.
Line: 243

#0 /vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/home/mipxidih/...', '%message%\nLine:...')
#2 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(141): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
#6 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(464): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
#7 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(445): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<body>\n   <refe...')
#8 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(Array)
#9 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()
#10 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#11 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(253): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#12 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(875): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#13 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#14 /vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#15 /vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(43): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), 'luxury-home-ver...')
#16 /generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute(NULL)
#17 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#18 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#20 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#22 /vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#25 /vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#31 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#33 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#34 /index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#35 {main}
```

gone back in production with

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

and now i'm getting

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Wishlist\Block\AbstractBlock in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111 Stack trace:
#0 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Wishlis...', Array) 
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Wishlis...') 
#2 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Wishlis...') 
#3 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('MGS\\Mpanel\\Help...') 
#4 /app/code/MGS/Mpanel/Bl in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111
```

(that googling looks like a very common error as a lot of sites are cached by google with this error) someone can point me to a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the dev mode issue finding "ifConfig" in my template's xml files and replacing it to "ifconfig" (or deleting from the xml if useless).

than solved the error after going in production mode executing `composer install`